# Promise all async operations

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I've two async  operation which take a different time to excute , let's say

> 1 . one operation take 1 sec to execute
>    2 . other operation take 10
>   sec to execute

I want to use promise.all that the both operation will be excuted in parallel ( I know that in js there is no concept of multi treading...) 
and both execute on the same tread,
when I use promise all  I **expect that op1 will be finish before op2** which doesn't happen...any idea what am I missing here?
(lets say op1 save something small in my server(1 sec) op2(10sec) and when I check after 1 sec I don't see that op1 finish just after both finish... ).
I know that the promise all will be finish after both will be finished (resolved).

```
Promise.all([op1, op2]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values);
}, reason => {
  console.log(reason)
});
```

Comment: How do you know that op1 finished before op2 ? Could you provide code for `op1` and `op2` ? Promise.all() won't resolve until _all_ of the promises in the array (e.g. `op1` _and_ `op2`) have completed (resolved/rejected). Only after both have completed will Promise.all() resolve and execute your code in `.then()`

Comment: "*which doesn't happen*" - please show your actual code and tell us *what* does not happen

Comment: Please consider reading about the difference between concurrency and parallelism. While in NodeJS the UI JS thread is by default single-threaded, i/o operations are certainly concurrent.

Comment: "*when I check after 1 sec I don't see that op1 finish*" - you should not "check" after some timeout, if you want to wait for that operation then use `op1.then(…)`.

Comment: @Bergi - if I put both operations in the array and I know that the first operation take 1 sec and the second take 10 second,(lets say exactly this times ...) when should I expect that the first operation will be finish ?

Comment: @JennyM: It will finish when it finishes. But `Promise.all` specifically wants for **all** of the promises to finish before fulfilling its promise. If you want early notification, as bergi says, use `op1`'s promise, not `Promise.all`'s. (You can use both, if that's useful.)

Comment: *"I want to use promise.all that the both operation will be excuted in parallel"* Note that using `Promise.all` doesn't have anything to do with whether the operations are executed in parallel. All it does is give you a promise that will be fulfilled when either operation fails or when both operations succeed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - if I put both operations in the array and I know that the first operation take 1 sec and the second take 10 second,(lets say exactly this times ...) when should I expect that the first operation will be finish ?

Comment: @JennyM: As I said above, when it finishes. If it takes 1 second, it'll finish in one second. If the JavaScript thread isn't blocked doing something else, a callback on `op1.then` will get fired after one second. A callback on `Promise.all([op1, op2]).then` will get fired when **both** operations finish (if the JavaScript thread isn't blocked).

Comment: @JennyM Promises are not exactly time bound operations. `Promise.all` will wait till all the promises are resolved successfully, or till the rejection of any of the promises.

Comment: @JennyM You already said that you "*know that the promise all will be finish after both will be finished*". It does not influence at all when the first operation will finish. You're passing in a promise, the operation will start when you call it (and finish 1 sec later), it does not matter what happens with the result (the promise) or that it is awaited by the `Promise.all`.

Comment: `Promise.all` returns a promise. In your case, even if `op1` finishes first, as `all` will wait till all the promises in the array to be resolved, it will resolve the promise returned by it only after `op2` also resolves.

Comment: @Bergi - so just to verify :) you said that if I pass a async operation to promise all that take 1 sec and the array will contain another operation that take more then 1 sec ,I should expect that this operation will be finished after about 1 sec?

Comment: It is not known per se *when* each operation will be started. That depends on the timing and order of their creation and the state of the event loop. Should `op2` start first **and it is a blocking operation**, the thread will be occupied with executing `op2` and `op1` won't start until that's finished. If `op2` is asynchronous and can yield to `op1` until some background event happens… well… who knows *when* `op1` will start and finish exactly… Overall, both operations will finish in about 10 seconds, or about 11 seconds, depending on which yields the thread and when.

Comment: @JennyM Yes. `op1()` will work the same regardless whether used in a `op1().then(…)` or `Promise.all([op1(), …])` context or somewhere else.

Comment: @Bergi - thanks bergi :)

Comment: @Bergi - so in promise all when does both operation are started ? there is no multi tread ...ow does it determine which promise to start in the array?

Comment: The operations start when you call them. This has nothing to do with `Promise.all`. A promise only represents a result, not an operation. That `Promise.all` consumes the results does not change anything. Just think of `var p1 = op1(); var p2 = op2(); Promise.all([p1, p2]);` - you can omit the third statement and they still will get started like any asynchronous function.

Comment: @Bergi - thanks but this is confusing since I put then inside array and they don't start until the promise all is called, and then the promise all should call it in "parallel" (from the array)so it call both on the same time exactly ? (event loop?)

Comment: @JennyM "*they don't start until the promise all is called*" - of course they do! They start when you are doing the operation, regardless when or whether  `Promise.all` is called on the resulting promises. "*promise all should call it in "parallel"*" - No! They are parallel because they both are asynchronous, and started so that they run at the same time. `Promise.all` is just a utility to await multiple asynchronous results and has nothing to do with parallelism.

Comment: I think that because until the following line is not excused you will not see any results (assume they print something...) in the console Promise.all([op1, op2]), now function op1 and op2 are started , my question is there is some minor delay between then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use promise.all that the both operation will be excuted in parallel...

Note that using `Promise.all` doesn't have anything to do with whether the operations are executed in parallel. All it does is give you a promise that will be resolved when both operations succeed or rejected when *either* operation fails.

Let's look at your code, see comments:

```
Promise.all([op1, op2]).then(values => { 
  // This will happen when BOTH op1 and op2 are done
  console.log(values);
}, reason => {
  // This will happen when EITHER op1 OR op2 fails
  console.log(reason);
});
```

So if `op1` takes one second and `op2` takes 10 seconds and we assume they're both successful, your callback will be executed 10 seconds later (when `op2` finishes). If you know `op1` only takes a second, then it's likely that `op1` finished several seconds before your `Promise.all` callback was called.

If you want notification when `op1` completes, use `then` on `op1`. You can do that in isolation, or you can do it and also use `Promise.all` to get a notification when both are complete.

This example, using `setTimeout` to emulate the actions, may help you understand; in the below, `op1` takes 100ms and `op2` takes 1000ms. It assumes both operations succeed, for simplicity:

```js
var start = Date.now();
var op1 = startOp1();
var op2 = startOp2();
op1.then(function() {
  // Fires when op1 is successful; doesn't care about op2
  console.log("op1 done after " + (Date.now() - start) + "ms");
});
op2.then(function() {
  // Fires when op2 is successful; doesn't care about op1
  console.log("op2 done after " + (Date.now() - start) + "ms");
});
Promise.all([op1, op2]).then(function() {
  // Fires when BOTH ops are successful
  console.log("both done after " + (Date.now() - start) + "ms");
});

function startOp1() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve();
    }, 100);
  });
}
function startOp2(flag) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Note: You've said both operations are async, so I've assumed that in the above.

Comment: *"So if op1 takes one second and op2 takes 10 seconds…"* …and one or both are *blocking* then the callback will *probably* be executed *11* seconds later… :)

Comment: @deceze: The OP has said they're both async, which I take to mean they don't block the JavaScript thread. But yes, if the nature of what they're doing means they end up geting serialized (both trying to act on the same mutually-exclusive thing even outside the JavaScript thread), naturally they'll stack up.

Comment: so when does both operation will be started, I ask it since there is no multi tread in promise all ...?how does it determine which promise to start in the array?

Comment: @JennyM: `Promise.all` does absolutely nothing to start the processes; they're *already started* by the time you're passing their promises into `Promise.all`. They were started by whatever you called to get those promises (`startOp1` and `startOp2` in the above).

Comment: thanks but this is confusing since I put then inside array and they don't start until the promise all is called, and then the promise all should call it in "parallel" (from the array)so it call both on the same time exactly ? (event loop?)

Comment: @JennyM: *"thanks but this is confusing since I put then inside array and they don't start until the promise all is called"* Yes, they do. Why do you think they don't? See my comment above: *"... they're already started by the time you're passing their promises into `Promise.all`. They were started by whatever you called to get those promises (`startOp1` and `startOp2` in the above)."* You seem to be hung up on `Promise.all` having something to do with starting the operations. It doesn't. Nothing whatsoever.

Comment: because until the following line is not excused you will not see any results (printing) in the console Promise.all([op1, op2])

Comment: @JennyM: That's just *observing* the processes and their completion. It has nothing to do with them *starting*.

Comment: so when this line is excuted Promise.all([op1, op2])  they both started in the same time?

Comment: @JennyM: Again: `Promise.all` has nothing, whatsoever, to do with starting the operations. They're **already started** before you call `Promise.all`. They were started by whatever it was you got the promises from.

Answer (score -1):

> when I use promise all I expect that op1 will be finish before op2 which >doesn't happen...any idea what am I missing here?

All individual promises inside the array blocks execute asynchronous and get to .then() only after all promises are resolved successfully.

Try using console.log('op1 done') and console.log('op2 done') in-between the timer function and resolve function of op1 and op2 respectively. The output  seen on the consoles will be:

```
    op1 done //after 1 sec
    op2 done //after 10 sec
    ['op1 done','op1 done'] //immediately follows the above one
```

This should make you believe the async nature. Also let me put one more visible example, where a text gets saved from browser in the below code with Promise p2 completing before Promise p1. Within that time period of 5 min (p1); the file (using p2) will be saved in the system before .then() executes

```
    var FileSaver = require('file-saver');

    var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5 * 60 * 1000, 'Executed Promise p2');                         
    // 5 min timer
    }); 

    var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"],
    {type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"});                                                            
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob
    , "hello world.txt");
    // Not tested it; from page: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/
    console.log('done with Promise p1');
    resolve('Executed Promise p1')
    }); 

    Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => { 
    console.log(values); // ['Executed Promise p1','Executed Promise p2'] 
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

For **op1 to be finished before op2**, can be used one of the below options - 
1. Promise Chaining explained [here](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)
2. Generators provided in ES6. 
3. Async-Await provided in ES7

Because Promise.all() ensures parallel execution not one after the other.